# close excel file during the display for the update

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

i read the data from excel sheet to display it, i need to do some update in the excel every 4 hours for that i need that the excel sheet run only with the web app and closed after the display.
this is my controller:

```
 //Read data from Total ProdPlan excelSheet
            string path4 = "D:/Project/TProdPlan.xlsx";

        Excel.Application application4 = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook4 = application4.Workbooks.Open(path4);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet4 = workbook4.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Range range4 = worksheet4.UsedRange;
        List<TProdPlan> ListTProdPlan = new List<TProdPlan>();
        for (int row = 2; row <= range4.Rows.Count; row++)

        {
            TProdPlan S = new TProdPlan();
            S.Num= (((Excel.Range)range4.Cells[row, 1]).Text);
            S.stat = (((Excel.Range)range4.Cells[row, 2]).Text);





            ListTProdPlan.Add(S);

        }

        ViewBag.ListTProdPlans = ListTProdPlan;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this code i can close the excel sheet from the process after access to the data.

```
workbook.close(0);
application.Quit();
```